# Proof for Wick's theorem (non-interacting case)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, many-body, wick-theorem

I follow the proof of Wick's theorem for a non-interacting case in "Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics (Bruus, Flensberg)", Ch 11.6.

In that chapter, above (11.75), the book states,

"Take now for example the case when $\tau_{i}$ is next to $\tau'_{j}$. There are **two** such terms in (11.72)..."

What (11.75) is,

$$\mathcal{G}_{0}^{(n)}=[\cdots \theta(\tau_{i}-\tau'_{j}) \cdots] \ \Big < \cdots \hat{c}_{\nu_{i}}(\tau_{i}) \hat{c}_{\nu'_{j}}^{\dagger} (\tau'_{j}) \cdots \Big > \pm [\cdots \theta(\tau'_{j}-\tau_{i}) \cdots] \ \Big < \cdots \hat{c}_{\nu'_{j}}^{\dagger}(\tau'_{j}) \hat{c}_{\nu_{i}}(\tau_{i}) \cdots \Big >$$

and the definition of $\mathcal{G}_{0}^{(n)}$ (equivalent as (11.72)) is,

$$\mathcal{G}_{0}^{(n)}=(\nu_{1}\tau_{1},\cdots,\nu_{n}\tau_{n};\nu'_{1}\tau'_{1},\cdots,\nu'_{n}\tau'_{n})=(-1)^{n} \Big < T_{\tau} \Big [\hat{c}_{\nu_{1}}(\tau_{1}) \cdots \hat{c}_{\nu_{n}}(\tau_{n}) \hat{c}_{\nu'_{n}}^{\dagger}(\tau'_{n}) \cdots \hat{c}_{\nu'_{1}}^{\dagger}(\tau'_{1}) \Big ] \Big >$$

However, I think there are more cases which satisfy that $\tau_{i}$ is next to $\tau'_{j}$. For example, in the case of 2-particle Green's function, there are many time-ordering cases that $\tau_{1}$ is larger than $\tau'_{2}$ such as,

$$\tau_{1}>\tau'_{2}>\tau_{2}>\tau'_{1}$$

$$\tau_{2}>\tau_{1}>\tau'_{2}>\tau'_{1}$$

$$\tau_{2}>\tau'_{1}>\tau_{1}>\tau'_{2}$$

This multiplicity gives more terms for (11.75).

Now, evaluating $\mathcal{G}_{0i}^{-1} \mathcal{G}_{0}^{n}=-\partial_{\tau_{i}}^{\theta} \mathcal{G}_{0}^{(n)}$, which $\partial_{\tau_{i}}^{\theta}$ means the derivative only for $\theta$-functions in $\mathcal{G}_{0}^{n}$, it becomes ((11.76) in the book),

$$-\partial_{\tau_{i}}^{\theta} \mathcal{G}_{0}^{(n)}=([\cdots] \ \Big < \cdots \hat{c}_{\nu_{i}}(\tau_{i}) \hat{c}_{\nu'_{j}}^{\dagger}(\tau'_{j}) \cdots \Big > \mp [\cdots] \ \Big < \cdots \hat{c}_{\nu'_{j}}^{\dagger}(\tau'_{j}) \hat{c}_{\nu_{i}}(\tau_{i}) \cdots \Big >) \delta(\tau_{i}-\tau'_{j})$$

Combining both terms makes $\big [\hat{c}_{\nu_{i}}, \hat{c}_{\nu_{j}}^{\dagger} \big ]_{B,F}=\delta_{\nu_{i},\nu'_{j}}$ (equal-time commutation relations for $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{c}^{\dagger}$), then reaching (11.79), it should be,

$$-\partial_{\tau_{i}}^{\theta} \mathcal{G}_{0}^{(n)}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \delta_{\nu_{i},\nu'_{j}} \delta(\tau_{i}-\tau'_{j}) (-1)^{x} \mathcal{G}_{0}^{(n-1)} (\underbrace{\nu_{1}\tau_{1},\cdots,\nu_{n}\tau_{n}}_\text{without i};\underbrace{\nu'_{1}\tau'_{1},\cdots,\nu'_{n}\tau'_{n}}_\text{without j})$$

Note that $\hat{c}$-$\hat{c}$ neighboring cases vanish since the equal time commutator $\big [\hat{c}_{\nu_{i}}, \hat{c}_{\nu_{j}} \big ]_{B,F}=0$.

But in my case, because of the multiplicity mentioned above, I got,

$$(2n-1) \ \delta_{\nu_{i},\nu'_{j}} \ \delta(\tau_{i}-\tau'_{j}) \ \cdots$$

instead of $\delta_{\nu_{i},\nu'_{j}} \ \delta(\tau_{i}-\tau'_{j}) \ \cdots$ given by the book. Due to the factor $(2n-1)$, I cannot get the correct result. How can I reduce this multiplicity to get the correct one like (11.79)?

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful. You are more likely to get an answer if you include enough information that people without a copy of Bruus and Flensberg can answer. At a minimum what is (11.72)?

Comment: OK, I will edit my question. Thank you for advice.

Comment: I will also add that it is difficult to follow the question when so much of the notation is specific to the book you're asking about. Nonetheless, I will also mention that Wick's theorem is covered in essentially any QFT book. A standard reference would be Peskin and Schroeder, but there is no shortage of books on the topic.